# Quickly vectorise 3D numpy array multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting

I have 3 numpy arrays, F, B, Q.

```
F.shape = (d,l)
B.shape = (l,d)
Q.shape = (l,d,d)
```

with l much bigger than d

I want to perform this operation:

```
A = np.zeros(shape=(d,d))
for ii in range(0,d):
    for jj in range(0,d):
        A[ii,jj] = np.sum(F[ii,:]*B[:,jj]*Q[:,ii,jj])
```

how can I quickly vectorise this using numpy?

If the first dimension of Q did not exist (i.e. Q was just a square matrix) then of course I could do
`A = np.multiply(np.matmul(F,B),Q)`
It feels like there should be similar one liner for a three dimensional Q.

Comment: Ah, I think I can do:
```A = np.einsum('il, lj, lij->ij', F, B, Q)```

Comment: `(Q*F.T[:,:,None]*B[:,None]).sum(0)` sees to work as well.  I derived it from the two steps identified by  `einsum_path(...., optimize=True)`.  'lij,il->lij', 'lij,lj->ij'